# Creating unbound service in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-service, kotlin, android-service-binding

I'm trying to create a simple unbound service in kotlin, but I can't. When I override `onBind()` method in Java I can return `null`, but in kotlin it says I'm only allowed to return `IBinder` and not `IBinder?`, that means it can't be `null`. Any ideas how to fix that except rewriting MyService class into Java?

[SOLVED] Thank you, guys! I can realy change `IBinder` to `IBinder?`. It works!!

Comment: What version of kotlin are you using? Using 1.0.3, when I converted a service the method signature was `override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder?` and generating the override in Android Studio gave me `override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder` but I was able to change that to `IBinder?` without issue

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Enrico mentioned you can change a type of `IBinder` to `IBinder?` and it will be still matching the interface.

An example is below:

```
override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
   return null
}
```

In general, be careful when using Android Studio to override Android methods. The real problem comes when it generates non-null type when the system actually can return a null reference. It causes runtime kotlin exceptions you really don't expect.

If I remember correctly I had a lot of issues when overloading `Fragment` class and methods related to `View` creation.